# Is there a way to display a image in WPF stored in memory?

Tags: wpf, image, controls, bitmap, operations

What I got is something like a screenshot making application. (managed to serialize, thank god!!!) When a button is clicked a screenshot is taken by accessing a handling classe's method. now the tricky part is that the class has another method for operating with the above said result, in such a manner than when the respective handling method is called, a window is created(shown) and the bitmap image should go into a display container in that window. The problem is that so far, I've noticed that in WPF the image control's source cannot be attribuited to a variable which stores the image. How can i display the image stored in that variable without having to save it first,get uri,etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an image from a memory stream, this has been well documented by many people. Here are two links that may get you started:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/44637/166282.aspx

http://www.wpftutorial.net/Images.html

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the links slugster. Here's how I did it:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
sBmp = gBmp; //note: gBmp is a variable that stores the captured image and passes it on to the method that uses sBMP as a distribuitor of the variable holding the captured image data
//variable that holds image
sBmp.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Bmp);
//my buffer byte
byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
//Create new MemoryStream that has the contents of buffer
MemoryStream bufferPasser = new MemoryStream(buffer);
//Creates a window with parents classthatholdsthismethod and null
Edit childEdit = new Edit(this, null);
childEdit.Show();
//I create a new BitmapImage to work with
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = bufferPasser;
bitmap.EndInit();
//I set the source of the image control type as the new BitmapImage created earlier.
childEdit.imgImageCanvas.Source = bitmap;
childEdit.Activate();
```

I've basically combined what I had found on those pages with some info I found on how to pass on a bmp to a memstream. I got this to work 100% :)